# Fixed padding on ImageViews in UITableViewCells?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, imageview

I am trying to center the `UIImageView` in one of the cells in my `UITableView`. To do this, I had to create a subclass of the `UITableViewCell`, and update the position of the `imageView` in `-(void)layoutSubviews`. I've tried several methods, basically like this:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.imageView.center = self.center;
}
```

This does not work the way I want it to. It seems like there's a fixed padding for the `imageView` or something like that, cause the center of the `imageView` after this is actually a bit down to the right of the cell's actual center.
If I write something like `self.imageView.center.x = self.center.x;`, the image is centered in height, but a bit too far to the right. So I figure I have to write something like `self.imageView.center.x = self.center.x - someValue;` in order to get it right, if a padding is the issue. Where can I find this padding, and will it proportion right for different devices? Or maybe there is no padding, and this is caused by something else?

By the way, it's a **grouped** tableView, if that can have something to do with it..

And, the height and width of the UIImageView should be less than of the cell, so I don't think this is what's pushing it down.

I've temporarily added a border to my images just to see how much it's off by, and I think it's quite disturbing.. The code you see in the image is the only code added to the custom cell class.

This is what I get:
[image: Result]

Comment: Do you add the image view to the `contentView` of the table cell?

Comment: @AndrewTetlaw I am not adding anything, the cell has an imageView by default. Self.imageView is accessible, and I'm able to move it around, it's just that it doesn't move where I tell it to, as if theres a 20px padding or something..

Comment: Sorry, I thought if you were using a custom cell you were doing something custom. Sounds like you might need a custom cell, you can build it in interface builder and put the image view where ever you like.

Comment: @AndrewTetlaw Yeah, the only reason I'm creating the custom cell is to center the damn imageView.. I've added an image to my question, you can see what's happening.. I don't understand why.

Comment: Please choose / vote on an answer.

Comment: @cdo Since none of you actually provided a solution to my problem I feel I shouldn't accept them as answers. Don't take me wrong, both of you helped me a lot on the way, but until I've found out how to solve the actual question at hand, I won't. The way I'm thinking is that if anyone else stubles upon this, they'll get nothing out of reading your answers. Later when I fix this problem, if no answers have been provided, I will post the way I did it as answer myself and link your answers as possible explanation, if they are. I have now also upvoted;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By the way, it's a grouped tableView, if that can have something to do with it..

YUP!

Grouped table views have padding - or margin - whatever it is, it's inconvenient. I don't post a code answer here because there's many unique ways to deal with your issue, but knowing that the UITableView definitely does this for grouped table views is a start. There are other posts on here that can help you find ways to deal with the spacing caused by grouped table views. Good luck!

Comment: Really?! Do you know of a way to find that padding programmatically? So that I can take ish: `self.imageView.center = self.contentView.center-padding;` I hate using constants, so I'd rather avoid writing `contentView.center-20.0;`

Comment: I'm talking about a padding on the inside of each cell here, not on the tableView itself.. If you still think there's a padding, I find it really weird the `self.contentView.center` of the cell doesn't include it. Like, the center is set, and THEN they add padding. Doesn't make sense to me..

Comment: I agree that it would be best to find a way to do this programmatically, however there is no easy way proved by Apple to do so. The best attempts to do so that I've seen still rely on constants or other ugly solutions. Just keep in mind that this margin could be different on a different device, in a different orientation, etc. So whatever you decide to do, please keep this in mind when designing your app. If you are ONLY designing for say portrait iPhone app, you are safe to stick with a simple constant, but the more devices and orientations you support the more complex this becomes.

Comment: Cells have to allow for resizing, animating in and out of edit mode, and so on. So I guess it's not surprising they have a lot of internal layout logic.

Comment: Try changing your table style and you will immediately see how the table has added or removed some padding based on the style.

Comment: You could try subclassing and overriding layoutSubviews to get more control over your layout as @AndrewTetlaw has suggested. It's one of many ways to work around the problem, it's up to you to decide what works for you.

Comment: @cdo I think I'll just hardcode the constants.. Even thought it's both orientations for all devices. overriding so much for just a single imageView sounds to hard.. And you're right cdo, when changing the style of the tableView to `Simple`, the image centers properly.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.center = self.contentView.center;
    self.imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;

    self.contentView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    self.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Alternatively you could make use of the `backgroundView`:

```
UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"]];

[bg addSubview:img];
img.center = bg.center;

self.backgroundView = bg;
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me.. I've now added a border to the imageView to see how much off it is, and I'd say it's about 20px space on the right side, and 60px on the left.. It also looks like it's about 1px pushed down, but that may be right.

Comment: Anything else in the table cell? Some more detail able that might help Also can you paste a link to the image file?

Comment: Link? I took it just now and uploaded it directly here, don't know if there's a link to it.. There's not much to see though, just that the imageView clearly is way to the right.

Comment: It is the first row in a grouped tableView.

Comment: So I added my results above. Add a border to your contentView and compare the result? Is your table in edit mode? Also what's the rect on your imageView it looks bigger than the default.

Comment: Well, as you see, it does actually not work.. Your icons are pushed about 10px to the right.. Your images aren't centered.

Comment: And yes, this is on iPad, the height for the row with the image is 115, and it appears the imageView is 380x114. Btw, did you realise you proved my problem with your image?

Comment: Heh. No I didn't, oh well.

Comment: Don't you find it weird that the 'padding' or whatever we should call it gets added AFTER center is set, so that the center-variable gets totally wrong..?:S Anyway, what I'm looking for now is a way to programmatically get the padding so that I can say `imageview.center = self.center-padding;`-ish.. When I search for `grouped tableview padding` I only get a lot of posts about the space between cells, and the space outside the tableview.. I can't find it anywhere. English isn't my native language, so I'm thinking padding might not be the correct word to use here..?

Comment: I've added a suggestion above to use the backgroundView instead which avoids the layout logic.

Comment: A good suggestion, but I'm afraid it won't work here.. The view I'm working on now is a custom view I've made, which contains two tableViews. The one in the picture is the rightmost tableView, and they are both on the same UIView. I guess I'll just have to make the constant. So far I've figured out the padding is 31px in portrait on iPad..  Yay me!